# How should I transform a hierarchical Excel pivot table to XML schema

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, xml, data-structures

I work at a natural history museum and need to generate labels for drawers in our collection that have taxonomies of the stored specimens. I have a spreadsheet of each taxon stored in a drawer as a separate row (meaning there's multiple rows to a drawer), as shown below.

Spreadsheet of specimen taxa in each drawer:

[image]

I've create a pivot table that transforms the data into a hierarchical tree like structure, more or less mirroring the way I would like the labels to be configured (below).

Pivot table of taxa in each drawer:

[image]

I would like to create an XML document that mirrors the pivot table's hierarchical structure so that I can automate the generation of drawer labels in InDesign. I'm not very comfortable with XML schema and even less so with how to export flat tabular data to them.

**If there is a Python solution, I would love to see y'all's thoughts or maybe there's an easy way to do it with Excel's built in XML exporter. 
Really appreciate the help!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the python libraries pandas and dicttoxml to handle this task quite easily.

Say you have the data in a file called data.csv. Then you can use this (a little hacky) code snippet to transform it into the xml format you want:

```
from collections import defaultdict

import pandas as pd
from dicttoxml import dicttoxml

data = pd.read_csv("./data.csv", sep=";")

xml_dictionary = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(str))))

for drawer, drawer_data in data.groupby(by="Drawer"):
    for class_, class_data in drawer_data.groupby(by="Class"):
        for subclass, subclass_data in class_data.groupby(by="Subclass"):
            for suborder, suborder_data in subclass_data.groupby(by="Suborder"):
                for family, family_data in suborder_data.groupby(by="Family"):
                    xml_dictionary[drawer][class_][subclass][suborder] = family

result = dicttoxml(xml_dictionary, custom_root='Labels', attr_type=False)
open('./result.xml', 'wb').write(result)
```

This way you don't even need to make use of the excel pivot table you created!